# Problem when I delete a record on my firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to delete a record from my database and it work well only when in the database there is only one record and when there are more then one it works bad.

I delete only the item with specific date that i pass to the function.

This is my database:

[image: Database structure]

This is the class where I delete the item on swipe:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;
    private  View rootView;
    TextView titoloHome,sottotitoloHome,finePagina;

    DatabaseReference reference;
    RecyclerView recyclerViewMieiAllen;
    ArrayList<MieiAllenamenti> list;
    AllenamentiAdapter mieiAllenamentiAdapter;
    Button btnAddNew;
    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment HomeFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static HomeFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);


        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);

        }

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,@NonNull ViewGroup container,
                             @NonNull Bundle savedInstanceState)  {



        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        titoloHome = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.titoloHome);
        sottotitoloHome = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.sottotitoloHome);
        finePagina = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.finePagina);
        btnAddNew = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnAddNew);

        //lavoro con i dati
        recyclerViewMieiAllen=rootView.findViewById(R.id.mieiallenamentiRecyclerView);
        recyclerViewMieiAllen.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(rootView.getContext()));
        list=new ArrayList<MieiAllenamenti>();


        ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper=new ItemTouchHelper(simpleCallback);
        itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerViewMieiAllen);
        try {
            //prendo i dati dal database
            reference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("WorkoutApp");
            reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange( DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    // set code to retrive data and replace layout
                    for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                    {
                        MieiAllenamenti p = dataSnapshot1.getValue(MieiAllenamenti.class);
                        Log.d("uz",""+dataSnapshot1.getValue(MieiAllenamenti.class));
                        Log.d("uz",""+p.titleAllenamento);
                        list.add(p);
                    }
                    Log.d("LISTA",""+list.toString());
                    Context contexts = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
                    mieiAllenamentiAdapter = new AllenamentiAdapter(contexts, list);
                    recyclerViewMieiAllen.setAdapter(mieiAllenamentiAdapter);
                    Log.d("","SET ADAPTER");
                    Log.d("",mieiAllenamentiAdapter.getItemCount()+"");
                    mieiAllenamentiAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "non ci sono dati",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

        }catch (Exception e){}

        btnAddNew.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {

                    Intent a =new Intent(getActivity(),NuovoAllenamento.class);
                    startActivity(a);
                }catch (Exception e){}
            }
        });

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return rootView;
    }

ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleCallback=new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0,ItemTouchHelper.LEFT ) {
        @Override
        public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
           int position=viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
            switch (direction){
                case ItemTouchHelper.LEFT:
                    /*
                    reference.removeValue().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                        }
                    });*/

                    Log.d("POSIZIONE",position+"");
                    Log.d("viewHolder",viewHolder.toString()+"");
                    Log.d("mieiAllenamentiAdapter",mieiAllenamentiAdapter.getData().toString());

                    new Thread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            //this is a http request
                            DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                            Query applesQuery = ref.child("WorkoutApp").orderByChild("dateAllenamento").equalTo(mieiAllenamentiAdapter.getData().toString());

                            applesQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                    for (DataSnapshot appleSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                        appleSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();
                                    }
                                    mieiAllenamentiAdapter.deleteItem(position);
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                    Log.e("TAG", "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }).start();
                    //     mieiAllenamentiAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);

                    break;


            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: There is quite a lot of code in your question. Is there any way you can reproduce the problem with less code, and preferably without needing any UI input? If you can hard-code the values with which to reproduce the problem, it is much more likely we can spot what's going wrong. Also see: [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted a few hundred lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.